# Arraylist removing first occurance,not an exact object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having datatable in jsf. after clicking add button, loading the list based on selected values. elements added in the list successfully.
add to the list,

```
public class CompanyProduct implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Getter @Setter private int id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "productId", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @Getter @Setter private Product product;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", referencedColumnName = "id")
        @Getter @Setter private Company company;

        @Setter @Getter private Double price;

        @Setter @Getter private Double sellingprice;

        @Column
        @Getter @Setter private Integer minQuantity;

        @Column
        @Getter @Setter private Integer maxQuantity;

        @Column
        @Getter @Setter private Integer leadTime;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="uom_group_item_id")
        @Getter @Setter private UomGroupItem uomGroupItem;

}

public void addToAssociation() {


        List<CompanyProduct> tmpList = new ArrayList<CompanyProduct>(companyproducts);

        for (Product p : selectedProducts) {
            boolean flag = false;

            for(CompanyProduct companyProduct: tmpList){
                if(companyProduct.getUomGroupItem() == null && companyProduct.getProduct() != null && companyProduct.getProduct().getId().equals(p.getId())){
                    flag = true;
                }
            }

            if(!flag){
                addCompanyProducts(p, null);
            }

            addUomGroupProduct(p);
        }
        selectedProducts = null;
        loadLazyProducts();
    }

private void addCompanyProducts(Product p,UomGroupItem item){
        CompanyProduct sg = new CompanyProduct();
        sg.setProduct(p);
        sg.setCompany(company);
        sg.setPrice((double) (p.getMrp()==null?0f:p.getMrp()));
        sg.setSellingprice((double) (p.getMrp()==null?0f:p.getMrp()));

        if(item != null){
            sg.setUomGroupItem(item);
        }

        companyproducts.add(sg);
    }
```

but problem is, when i go delete, doing the operation,

```
for (CompanyProduct sg : selectedToBeAssociatedProducts) {
        companyproducts.remove(sg);
    }
```

but its removing first occurrence in list. so may i know the reason for this problem. thanks in advance.

Please let me know if any queries.

Comment: add more code, like in delete operation what is the content of object

Comment: Did you override the `equals` method in your object?

Comment: @SachinGupta added more codes. i didn't do anything just passing the object only .

Comment: @ReazMurshed no.simply passing the object and remove from list

Comment: And what else do you expect to happen? Have you done any prior research like reading the javadoc for that method?

Comment: @GhostCat yeah. i found that reference are same inside list. but i don't know why. please find the code for adding the list.

Comment: Please find the edited question for ur reference.

Comment: Add code of CompanyProduct  class

Comment: @SachinGupta added CompanyProduct class

Comment: I think you need to set Id, for each object. In order to distinguish between objects.

Comment: Id is auto generated value. so i can't set Id value while adding to the list.

Comment: This will auto-generate only for JPA operations, for manual object creation you need to set yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156235/discussion-between-balasubramanian-and-sachin-gupta).

Comment: yes it will generate during persist with database

Comment: yes, here you are creating an Object manually. so need to set id manually too

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, see List API

```
remove(Object o) 

Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).
```

If you want to remove all occurrences use List.removeAll, like this

```
list.removeAll(Collectoins.singelton(obj);
```

Comment: please find the edited question for ur reference. i want to remove the exact object

Answer (score 2):

- `List.removeAll(Object value)` will remove every occurrence of value
- `List.remove(Object value)` will remove first occurrence of value
- `List.remove(int position)` will remove value at position

Answer (score 1):

Try the following piece of code. If it doesn't work. Please tell us why. Or else accept an answer to close this question

```
list.removeAll(Collectoins.singelton(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first item in the list. Do `list.remove(0)`

If you want to remove the first item in the list corresponding to a particular value. Do `list.remove(value)`

Comment: actually i want to remove the exact object only, not first occurrence. pl check edited question